# How to perform a switch button with flutter?

Tags: flutter

I'm new on flutter and I need to perform a button on my flutter app, I saw some packages ([custom_switch](https://pub.dev/packages/custom_switch), [toggle_switch](https://pub.dev/packages/toggle_switch)) online but the rendering is not exact as the design that I'll like to perform.  [image: here's the image of what I'd like to do]

Comment: Please share your codes on what you have tried

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of a similar design, so I guess you need to build it on your own.

The following could be the underlying logic, rounded borders etc you could add with containers.

```dart
Row(children: <Widget> [
  Flatbutton(
    color: (toggle ? color1 : color2),
    Text("on"),
    onPressed: () => toggle = !toggle,
  ),
  
  Flatbutton(
    color: (toggle ? color2 : color1),
    Text("off"),
    onPressed: () => toggle = !toggle,
  )
])
```

Comment: if this helped, accepting or upvoting the answer would be nice :-)